# SvelteKit: How to Use Named Slots Based on Route

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am fairly new to SvelteKit and can't figure out an issue related to slots. I'm trying to make an app layout that has a master and detail pane where the contents of the master and detail are determined based on the route.

Let's say I have a `__layout.svelte` file like this:

```
//-------------------------
// routes/__layout.svelte
//-------------------------
<main>
  <slot name="master" />
  <slot name="detail" />
</main>
```

Then I have another page like this (with several more route pages that are similar):

```
//-------------------------
// routes/users.svelte
//-------------------------

<div slot="master">
  Users master content...
</div>

<div slot="detail">
  Users detail content...
</div>
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/users` I just get an error that says I can't use `slot=""` in `users.svelte` because it's not inside a child component.

Am I going about this all wrong? How would you pull off a similar app layout in SvelteKit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're almost there, however you can't use named slots in __layout.svelte

That __layout component only receives one (default) slot. That slot contains the component of the matched route.

A solution would be to rename the __layout into a standalone component and use that inside the route.svelte:

```
//-------------------------
// lib/MasterDetail.svelte
//-------------------------
<main>
  <slot name="master" />
  <slot name="detail" />
</main>
```

```
//-------------------------
// routes/users.svelte
//-------------------------
<script>
import MasterDetail from "$lib/MasterDetail.svelte"
</script>

<MasterDetail>
  <div slot="master">
    Users master content...
  </div>

  <div slot="detail">
    Users detail content...
  </div>
</MasterDetail>
```

Another solution could be to restrict the route.svelte to only render the detail part and let the __layout render the master part.
Maybe look into [nested layouts](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/layouts#nested-layouts) and the [page store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-page) to detect which detail is active.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Knowing that the `__layout` can only have a single, default slot is the key piece I was missing. I have tried your suggested alternative and it works great. Thanks again!

Comment: I am having a similar issue where this does not seem to work. Basically I have full screen panels on some pages and they need to have the highest z-index. However in my layout I had to fiddle with z-index of main to make a "reveal" footer. On the pages with a panel, I'd like to put it outside of the `main` tag. I could solve it by having the main tag on each page, but it is not ideal. The alternative is have the panels in the layout and trigger them from pages, but again, not ideal. If anybody has a workaround for this?...

Comment: @Mig you could look into using portals https://github.com/romkor/svelte-portal for the full screen panels. That allows for differences in the component tree and dom tree.

Comment: @BobFanger Ah nice thank you! It is a bit like what we do with `svelte:head` for the head tag. Exactly what I'd like to do sometimes. I'll give it a try.